# Visual Studio 2013 detaches very often from process when MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

I have an MVC 5 app running in Visual Studio 2014 Update 4.

My app is running fine in VS2013. But very often (about 4 out of 5 times) the debugger suddenly detaches from the process.

While the website keeps running, I don't get (of course) any debug information / breakpoints anymore.

Does someone have a solution or a way to troubleshoot this?